# Optimizing hacker rank challenge 'Climbing the Leaderboard'

Tags: ruby, algorithm, optimization

The challenge is as such:

> Alice is playing an arcade game and wants to climb to the top of the
>   leaderboard and wants to track her ranking. The game uses Dense
>   Ranking, so its leaderboard works like this:
>
> The player with the highest score is ranked number  on the
>   leaderboard. Players who have equal scores receive the same ranking
>   number, and the next player(s) receive the immediately following
>   ranking number. For example, the four players on the leaderboard have
>   high scores of 100, 90, 90, and 80. Those players will have ranks 1,
>   2, 2, and 3, respectively. If Alice's scores are 70, 80 and 105, her
>   rankings after each game are 4th, 3rd and 1st

Essentially you have to return an array with her rankings after each game. I have working code but it times out on 4 of the tests. Here is my code:

```
def climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice)
    positions = []
    alice.each do |x|
        scores.insert(scores.index(scores.min_by { |y| (x-y).abs }) + 1, x)
        board = scores.group_by { |x| x }.sort_by { |k,v| v }.reverse
        positions << board.find_index { |k| k[0] == x } + 1
    end
    return positions
end
```

I am wondering what I can do to optimize it more?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the [Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Tip: Use `map`.

Comment: @tadman, it's not working code! If `scores = [100, 90, 90, 80]` and `alice = [70, 80, 105]`, `climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice) #=>  [4, 3, 1]` (correct), but now `scores #=> [100, 100, 90, 89, 90, 80, 70]`, so the method will yield incorrect results if executed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
def climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice)
  uniq_scores = scores.uniq << -1
  alice.map do |alice_score|
    uniq_scores.bsearch_index { |score| alice_score >= score } + 1
  end
end
```

[Array#bsearch_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index) has a computational complexity of O(log n), where `n = uniq_rankings.size`.

**Example**

```
scores = [100, 90, 90, 80]
alice  = [70, 80, 105]

climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice)
  #=> [4, 3, 1]
```

Comment: I appreciate you showing me a useful tool (binary search ruby method), unfortunately it still isn't executing within the given time limit.

Comment: I find that surprising as my method is O(n) to compute `uniq_rankings` and O(log n) to get the ranking, and that would seem to be the lower limit. What is the message you get that says it isn't executing within the time limit? I read the question at the [Hankerrank site](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem) and saw that scores of zero are possible, so I changed `0` to `-1`  in `uniq_rankings = rankings.uniq << -1`. (Hello TO from Victoria.)

Comment: thelacaning, I just ran this at hackerrank and it passed all the tests.

Comment: Clearly the good approach. Just a comment on efficiency: I don't know ruby, but it seems that you are not using the fact that Alice's scores are provided in ascending order. Depending on the input, some gain is possible by using it. The issue with this kind of problem is that inputs are unknown... anyway, if current code passed the test...

Comment: @Damien, I hadn’t noticed that Alice’s scores are guaranteed to be in ascending order but I now see that is the case. How could that fact be used to advantage?

Comment: The binary search can be restricted between last found index and min one. I know how to do it in C++, but in ruby...

Comment: Basically I agree with you. The issue is that we don't know the input. For example, let us assume that Alice last 10^5 scores correspond to first ranking... In this kind of problem, if the TL is 1s, when you get 1.01s you are a zero, and you are a heroe with 0.99s time score! But again, as you passed the tests...

Comment: @Damien, I suspected that’s what you had in mind. (What else could it be?) In Ruby, after getting each index `i` using `bsearch_index`, one would have to replace the array `scores` with an array of it's first `i+1` elements (no pointers in Ruby). Considering the overhead and the logarithmic nature of binary searches, I’m not convinced it would speed the calculations, but one could of course benchmark. (Readers: mentally reverse the order of this and the previous comment.)

Comment: @Cory Swoveland. I was incorrect. I made a mistake. Your code does execute in the required time.